# (Онлайн Радио своими руками) Audio-Stream не проигрывается через web. С чем может быть связано?

Tags: web-audio

Давно заметил, что некоторые audio-стримы по URL прекрасно проигрываются в WinAmp, но вот в Web не хотят, ни в какую.
Пример стрима:
http://uk2.internet-radio.com:8002/
Как такой стрим прописать для воспроизведения по средствам браузера?